# Handle multiple forms on same page PHP JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Ok!! I have various hidden forms on a page and on form submit `Shipping Address` of person is stored in Session.

Form are as below:

```
.chkhiddenform input {display:none}
```

Form 1

---

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal chkhiddenform" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bc_ship_zipcode" 
   name="bc_ship_zipcode" value="123456"/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bc_ship_name" 
   name="bc_ship_name" value="Test"/>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bc_address" 
   name="bc_address" value="Test Address 1 Address 2"/>
 <button type="submit" class="select_btn btn btn-white"><span>Deliver 
 Here</span></button>   
</form>
```

Form 2

---

```
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal chkhiddenform" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bc_ship_zipcode" 
   name="bc_ship_zipcode" value="123456"/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bc_ship_name" 
   name="bc_ship_name" value="Test 2"/>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bc_address" 
   name="bc_address" value="Test Address 1 Address 2 Address 3"/>
 <button type="submit" class="select_btn btn btn-white"><span>Deliver 
 Here</span></button>   
</form>
```

JQuery used to submit the hidden forms are as below:

```
$(".chkhiddenform").validate({
 var bc_name = $("#bc_ship_name").val();var bc_ship_zipcode = 
 $("#bc_ship_zipcode").val();var bc_address = 
 $("#bc_address").val();
 var dataString = 'bc_ship_name=' + bc_name + '&bc_ship_zipcode=' + 
                   bc_ship_zipcode + '&bc_address=' + 
                   bc_address
submitHandler: function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(response) {
           if(response=='success'){
              window.location.replace('next-screen');
           }
        }
     });
}
});
```

`Process.php` is as below:

```
$sql1 = "select * from `additional_address` WHERE `email` = ? ";
$result1 = 
DB::instance()->prepare($sql1)->execute(array($_SESSION['array']
['email']))->fetchAll();
$_SESSION['address'] = reset ($result1);
```

But always on submit, Form 1 values are getting to the next page. please let me know where is the problem?

Comment: Please do not answer. I found a solution myself. For those who all are facing same problem can refer to this tutorial and njoy.. `http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/submit-multiple-forms-jquery-ajax.html`

Comment: I Appended ID from DB in all form inputs and it is now workng awesome :)